# I want to autofill the username & password in external URL in PHP in a iFrame

Tags: php, iframe

I am stuck it in for 2 days I cant find any solution regarding this problem
The main problem is that I want to autofill the username & password from the when I click on the button

I searched so many solution in Stackoverflow but didn't helped me

I have a button when I click on it and iFrame popup loading the external URL. URL of the site which is loading is "https://bkwins.org/" in it successfully
Now I want to autofill the username & password of the site.
Can this be Acheiveable through the PHP curl methods?

Here is the following code

```
$url = 'https://bkwins.org/';
$myvars = "Hi";


$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec( $ch );
```

Comment: Can you add some punctuation to your text please because it's barely readable, never mind comprehensible. See also [ask].

Comment: I have re-edited the Text u can see @ADyson

Comment: Thanks. If you're loading something into an iframe then you'd surely need some JS to input data into the iframe

Comment: I can do this Because of the same Origin Policy I'm searching for another way

Answer (score 1):

No.

To populate the form you need to either:

- Run JavaScript on the page the form exists on.

  - You can't do this from your website due to the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)
  - A browser extension could do this, but you don't appear to be writing one
- Modify the HTML source code of the page

  - It isn't your site, so you can't do that.
  - You could fetch the page using PHP/cURL, modify the HTML, then serve the modified HTML to the user **from your own site** but that wouldn't be coming from the third party site.

Comment: How can I Fetch the page and modify the HTML 
Can I Share u my HTML Code?